# SubmitChanges()  не сохраняет результаты в БД

Tags: c#, linq, sql

Никаких ошибок нет в логах, запрос сохраняется, но такое ощущение, что контекст не видит изменений в классе. Проверил connectionString. Совпадает путь до .mdf тот, что в проекте, и тот, что прописан в Solution Explorer. WTF?

ЗЫ: Делал INSERT нового экземпляра объекта через new.

**Обновление**

```
namespace LinqToSqlExamples
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {

            TestDataContext db = new TestDataContext();
            db.Log = Console.Out;

            Customer cust = new Customer
            {
                CustomerID = 0,
                CustomerFirstName = "Vladislav",
                CustomerSecondName = "Volkov",
                CustomerAge = 24
            };

            db.Customers.InsertOnSubmit(cust);
            db.SubmitChanges();
            Console.ReadKey();

        }
    }
}
```

В качестве `connectionString` он использует это:

```
  <connectionStrings>
        <add name="LinqToSqlExamples.Properties.Settings.TestConnectionString"
            connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Test.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
            providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
```

В качестве базы данных я создал service-based Database.

Comment: Приведите пример кода

Comment: Зачем Add? Я сделал db.Customers.InsertOnSubmit(таблица).

Comment: @Vladislav  Romarov вы код приведите. А то догадываться, что вы сделали, а чего не сделали довольно сложно

Comment: Обновил ответ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А дело-то было действительно в контексте...

Скопировал контекст из Server Explorer  и сразу заработало, а с этим - нет, хотя путь до базы один и тот же... Просто не знал, что он так вот легко из Server Explorer может быть взят. = )))